# execution order of javascript code

Tags: javascript, promise, firefox-addon-webextensions

im new to Javascript and I would like to know why my "console.log('never reached')" code is never executed

I got this simple lines of code:

My content-script

```
function myFunction() {

    if (window.location.href.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('https://www.google.de/') > -1)
    {
        var myPort = browser.runtime.connect({name:"port-from-cs"});

        myPort.onMessage.addListener(function(m) {
          console.log(m.greeting);

        });

        console.log('never reached ');
    }
}
myFunction();
```

My background-script

```
var portFromCS;

function connected(p) {
  portFromCS = p;

  var allOpenWindows = browser.windows.getAll();

  allOpenWindows.then(function(result){ 
    portFromCS.postMessage({greeting: "Windows opened: " + result.length.toString()});                          
  }); 

}
browser.runtime.onConnect.addListener(connected);
```

After I enter google.de in my browser my content script connect to my background-script, then I count all open Windows and send the Message back to
content-script. In the console I can see the message but the last console.log is never reached. Whats wrong?

edit:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because window.location.href.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('https://www.google.de/') is giving you -1 and -1 cannot be greater than -1
If you replace -1 >= -1 your if block will execute

Comment: it jumps into the if block (in my code I got an another adress, not google) everything works fine till "console.log('never reached ');"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve..?

Comment: window.location.href.toString().toLowerCase() will give you the current url of the page which is running your script it's obvious that you are not running your script in https://www.google.de/ so window.location.href.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('https://www.google.de/') will always return -1, so if you change your equality sign to >= -1 (which is not correct) your if block will execute even if your script is not running in the html page rendered by 'https://www.google.de/" so your code will give message "not google"

Comment: After I received message from background script I want execute some other code, for example console.log but that code is never executed

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but your if block will execute only if you run your script on 'https://www.google.de/'

Comment: I will edit my post and add an screenshot, for better understanding.